# How can I make my own calculator with given string in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, calculator

I want to make my own calculator in terminal. I want something like: 
when I give this input `(5+2)*4-3` it has to make `()` part first then multiplication, then subtraction. How can I do that in linux terminal with bash script?

Comment: You can use `bc`

Comment: how can you give me some examples

Comment: Maybe have a read through this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $(((5+2)*4-3))
```

or using script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 = $(($1))"
```

for example.

There are also several [other ways](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-arithmetic.php). Or just search for "*bash arithmetic*"

Comment: thanks for solution

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `bc` would be the correct tool for this purpose:

```
$ echo "(5+2)*4-3" | bc
25
```

↳ https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html